# Nginx 500 error page without any error log

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, server

I am getting "500 internal server error". But, there is no error log anywhere. I am running ubuntu trusty via vagrant+virtual box on macOS Sierra.  [image]

Comment: are error logs enabled? paste your nginx config for that server

Comment: yes, error logs are enabled

Comment: also look into magento var log directory for logs.

Comment: in magento-error.log
´2017/03/30 13:11:40 [error] 27665#27665: *57 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while processing "/index.php", client: 192.168.10.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /martela/admin HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.10.10"´

Comment: in magento-access.logs has nothing which is specific to issue.
192.168.10.1 - - [02/Apr/2017:17:19:24 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 595 "http://192.168.10.10/materla" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36"
192.168.10.1 - - [02/Apr/2017:17:19:26 +0000] "GET /materla HTTP/1.1" 500 595 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36"

Comment: can you see other error message from your respond?

Comment: I am not able to figure out so far. It rendered index/default route but no other route. After sometime now it gives "500 error" for all routes.

Comment: Probably in the access log. When I get a 500 I see the log in access.log.

Answer (score 1):

According here https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-fix-an-unknown-internal-server-error-500-nginx-is-giving-me
Remove the line that set custom log location, and check log in default location (*/var/log/nginx*) might help.

Answer (score 0):

if magento is configured to write error log in a file but not to transfer error stack trace to nginx -- in this case nginx error log will be empty.
i would suggest to check magento config about that. at least in php-fpm we have as i described